# How can I display only values in json instead of key:value pairs?

Tags: php, jquery, json, mysqli

I have my mysqli query:

```
$fetchTransactions = "SELECT * FROM transaction WHERE client_id = '$client_id'";
$result = $mysqli->query($fetchTransactions);
$data = array();    
$data = $result->fetch_all( MYSQLI_ASSOC );
echo json_encode( $data );
```

and it returns the json as:

```
[{"transaction_id":"1","client_id":"2","total_price":"100.70","creation_date":"2015-10-18 03:00:00","unique_hash":"ABCDEF"},
{"transaction_id":"2","client_id":"2","total_price":"88.20","creation_date":"2015-10-18 04:00:00","unique_hash":"GHIJK"}]
```

Instead of this I would like to have a data in a form presented here:

```
{
  "data": [
    [
      "1",
      "2",
      "100.70",
      "2015-10-18 03:00:00",
      "ABCDEF"
    ],
    [
      "2",
      "2",
      "88.20",
      "2015-10-18 03:00:00",
      "GHIJK"
    ],
```

because I need this json format to feed the datatable taken from here: https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html

Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of converting `$data` to json, loop through it. `array_values` function will extract all array values from an associative array.

```
<?php 
 $newarray = array();
 foreach($data as $d){
  // save array values to $newarray
  $newarray['data'][] = array_values($d);
 }

$json_newarray = json_encode($newarray);

echo print_r($json_newarray, true);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to iterate through the row values and [`array_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) to ignore the keys (column names), you could do the following :

```
echo json_encode( array( 'data' => array_map('array_values', $data) ) );
```